# Blank and partially-blank buttons persist in taskbar after applications close

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

For all accounts on a particular Windows 7 Enterprise computer, taskbar buttons don't go away when windows & applications close. The text goes away, but the icon persists. The buttons do not resize, as they would if I'd closed an application that's pinned to the taskbar.

Eventually new windows don't seem to get taskbar buttons. I often end up with some completely blank buttons, and what look and act like the corners of taskbar buttons start to appear to the right of the full buttons.

This is best explained with a [image: Screenshot]

Restarting explorer.exe makes this go away for a little while, but not for long. This problem persists in Safe Mode. 
`sfc /scannow` does not report any problems. Switching to & from Aero has no effect. Unfortunately I have no restore points from before I first noticed this.

Has anyone come across this problem before? Any suggestions?